# fabricjs won't import background image after export is stringyfied

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, fabricjs

After I stringify a a canvas, when I try to import it again with `canvas.loadFromJSON()` it won't import the background image, but if I export the object and import it back it will.

Doesn't work:

```
function save(e) {
    var json = window._json = canvas.toJSON();
    canvas.clear();

    canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)), function(){
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

Works:

```
function save(e) {
    var json = window._json = canvas.toJSON();
    canvas.clear();

    canvas.loadFromJSON(json), function(){
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

Here is a fiddle that shows what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/dj2he6d8/3/

Any attempt to stringify the exported object ends up removing the background, while the objects are imported successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Kienz for answering at github:

> You misspelled the word height (imgObj.heigth).
>
> I also added fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 10; (Default = 2) - numbers got formated by using fixed-point notation.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1733